# Elixir find first matching element in two lists

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am fairly new to Elixir, and I have a small business problem. I am trying to localize data returned in an api call to my Phoenix middle tier. I am getting the user's browser languages and parsing those into a list. The order of the languages is relevant. I want to find the first matching language from the browser language list in my list of supported languages.

I could do this with nested loops and all that, but this seems like something Elixir could do more elegantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enum.find/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#find/3):

```rb
user = ~w|ge es it|
supported = ~w|it ru en|

Enum.find(user, 'en', fn l -> Enum.empty?([l] -- supported) end)
```

Here `'en'` is the default language to be returned as no matched were found. `[l] -- supported` (list distraction) would return `[l]` if there is no matches and `[]` if `l` exists in `supported`.

Or, alternatively, use nested `Enum.find/3`]:

```rb
Enum.find(user, 'en', fn l -> Enum.find(supported, & &1 == l) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your supported langs into a set:

```
supported_langs = ["a", "b", "c"]
user_langs = ["z", "s", "b", "a"]

supported_langs_set = supported_langs |> Enum.into(MapSet.new)

Enum.find(user_langs, fn user_lang ->
  MapSet.member? supported_langs_set, user_lang
end)
```

Looking up something in a set is fast v. traversing a supported_langs list over and over again looking for each user_lang.  However, if your lists are only a few elements long, it's not going to make much difference.

Comment: List of supported languages cannot contain more than ≈200 elements AFAICT :)